# fall back for main menu?

Tags: menus

I am new to WordPress, and am still trying to learn the in's and out's in much respect to this well known CMS.

I am wanting to know, if I should or must have a Fallback for main menu?

This is what I am working with:

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'xxxxxx' ),
) );
```

And here is the callback within my header.php file:

```
<nav>            
    <?php wp_nav_menu( 
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'Primary', 
        'menu' =>  'Primary',
        'container' => '', 
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="main">%3$s</ul>'  
    )); 
?>
</nav>
```

Like I said, I am new. So please, any help will be much welcome.

And if you could, please respond with an example.

Answer (score 8):

The parameter `fallback_cb` will be used when the user has no menu assigned to your `theme_location`. It should be a function that returns a string, but you can use `__return_false()` to suppress any output:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        // No menu available: no output.
        'fallback_cb'    => '__return_false'
    )
);
```

You should **always declare the fallback explicitly** to keep your code readable.

Take the example from TwentyEleven:

```
<?php 
/* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu 
falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary 
location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with 
the lowest ID is used. */ 
?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

That’s very confusing. One could think that the theme will now use the first available custom menu if there was no menu assigned to this theme location. **Wrong.** The list of pages will be used instead. Declaring a callback would have been much easier to understand.

The fallback will get all the menu arguments. You have to **inspect the `echo` parameter**, because WordPress will not take care of that for you. And make sure to respect the other arguments too to get a correctly styled output.

An advanced example: It returns nothing if there is no menu assigned to the theme location – and a link to the menu editor if the current user can actually create a menu:

```
/**
 * Menu fallback. Link to the menu editor if that is useful.
 *
 * @param  array $args
 * @return string
 */
function link_to_menu_editor( $args )
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    // see wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php for available arguments
    extract( $args );

    $link = $link_before
        . '<a href="' .admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) . '">' . $before . 'Add a menu' . $after . '</a>'
        . $link_after;

    // We have a list
    if ( FALSE !== stripos( $items_wrap, '<ul' )
        or FALSE !== stripos( $items_wrap, '<ol' )
    )
    {
        $link = "<li>$link</li>";
    }

    $output = sprintf( $items_wrap, $menu_id, $menu_class, $link );
    if ( ! empty ( $container ) )
    {
        $output  = "<$container class='$container_class' id='$container_id'>$output</$container>";
    }

    if ( $echo )
    {
        echo $output;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Now we can call this menu like this …

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'fallback_cb'    => 'link_to_menu_editor',
        'echo'           => FALSE
    )
);

echo $menu;
```

… and an admin will get a useful link within all the markup the theme’s stylesheet is expecting:

> [image]

A regular visitor will get nothing.

Comment: Neat little function here - very useful

Comment: _the menu with the lowest ID_ is shown only if `menu` (but not `theme_location`) is passed and `menu` does not match any menu.

Answer (score 2):

See [`wp_nav_menu()` in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

The default fall-back (the `fallback_cb` parameter) for `wp_nav_menu` is `'wp_page_menu'` so I think you should auto-magically have a page menu (a menu with every static page and only static pages) if you do not assign a primary menu.

Is this not the case?

Comment: I see....

So I guess I should just use this 'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',

Comment: you shouldn't have to.  that is the default.. you actually have to pass a null string to get rid of it.  are you not getting  a menu? do you have any pages in your blog?

Comment: That's not true. You have to unset it using `false`. Passing a `null` will simply leave the original fallback in.

Comment: You are correct. We're still waiting to hear if @MartyBoi is not seeing anything as a fallback, because it should already be happening by default right?

Comment: Yes... right :)